# Deactivate shortcut keys for Dijit Editor Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to use the dijit.Editor widget. I do not have the need for all the plugins, such as bold, italic, lists, etc. By not including them in the plugins list, they do not appear in the toolbar. But the shortcut key mapping is still present.

I tried to subclass dijit.Editor and override the setupDefaultShortcuts method, but this does not seem to solve the problem.

Is there a way to override the shortcut key mappings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you stated in the question works for me...  Don't even have to extend, just clobber the function by passing a new empty one in.

```
dojo.require('dijit.Editor');
dojo.ready(function() {
    var ed = new dijit.Editor({
        setupDefaultShortcuts: function(){},

    }).placeAt(dojo.body());
    ed.startup();
});
```

If you do want to extend, it's just as easy:

```
dojo.require('dijit.Editor');
dojo.ready(function() {
    dojo.declare('MiniEditor', dijit.Editor, {
        constructor: function() {
            //executes after inherited constructor, overriding plugins
            this.plugins = [];
        },
        setupDefaultShortcuts: function(){}
    });
    var ed = new MiniEditor({}).placeAt(dojo.body());
    ed.startup();
});
```

Comment: Hi Ken. I am trying to subclass the dijit.Editor class, and that is where the setupDefaultShortcuts does not work. Is there a way to override the method in the new subclass?

Answer (score 2):

I'm no means a dojo expert, so a better will likely come along, but one way that I found to accomplish this is by altering the member variable `_keyHandlers` within the editor class.

```
var editor = new dijit.Editor({plugins:plugins}, 
    dojo.byId('myEditor'));
delete editor._keyHandlers['b'];
```

The first line would create the new editor with the altered plugins list.  The second line deletes the key handler for `b` which would be bold.  You could do the same for any other keys you want to remove.  If you want to remove them all I'm guessing you could just set `_keyHandlers` equal to a new array.

I'm not sure why overriding setupDefaultShortcuts didn't work.  Did you override it in right class? It's a method in `dijit._editor.RichText` not `dijit.Editor`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why his idea didn't work for him either.  `dijit.Editor` extends from `dijit._editor.RichText`, so that much shouldn't be a problem.